# ANTLR4 : mismatched input while trying parse ':'

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to parse message using antlr4

```
:12B:DOCUMENT:some nice text
DOCUMENT2:some nice text
```

this is the expected output from the parser

heading -> 12B

subheading -> DOCUMENT

subheading -> DOCUMENT2

TEXT -> some nice text

TEXT -> some nice text

but on trying to extract the heading with the following grammar

```
grammar Simple;

para    :   heading*  EOF;

header  :   heading text ;
heading :   COLEN HEAD COLEN;


text    :   TEXT;




/* tokens */
TEXT    :   ~[\t]+   ; 
HEAD    :   [0-9A-Z]+  ;
COLEN : ':';
```

one supplying the input I am getting the following error

```
line 1:0 mismatched input ':12:nithin\n' expecting ':'
```

Could someone please tell me the possible cause and solution to parse the same? If I've missed anything, over- or under-emphasized a specific point, please let me know in the comments. Thank you so much in advance for your time.

Comment: Always print out the tokens recognized by the lexer in a loop before calling the parser. `TEXT :  ~[\t]+` matches almost everything (`\t` is never matched by any lexer rule) and HEAD and COLEN are never matched.

Comment: I tried with *:12:nithin*  i got the following as output `(header heading (text :12:nithin\n))` . How to correct it

Comment: It's hard to tell what the grammar should be, but this parses your input: `grammar Simple; para : (line (NL line) NL?) | NL* EOF ; line : COLON? TEXT (COLON TEXT)* ; TEXT : ~[:\n\r]+ ;COLON : ':' ;NL : [\n\r]+ ;`. You need to have a newline token because the first and second lines are two different "subheadings", yet `~[\t]+` matches new line characters.

Comment: Will I be able to parse heading and subheading separately ?

Comment: We don't have enough information to understand what you want, and what the input is. I am guessing you want extra parse tree structure, as in `grammar Simple; para : (one_or_the_other (NL one_or_the_other) NL?) | NL* EOF ; one_or_the_other : heading | subheading ; heading : COLON TEXT (COLON TEXT)* ; subheading : TEXT (COLON TEXT)* ; TEXT : ~[:\n\r]+ ; COLON : ':' ; NL : [\n\r]+ ;`. You can also parse each line separately with a separate call to the parser if you need to with this grammar.